# How can I make observable push the previous event as the very first value?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've got the following class:

```
public class PlayerPublisher {

    private final Flowable<Player> publisher;

    private ObservableEmitter<Player> emitter;

    public PlayerPublisher() {
        Observable<Player> playerUpdateObservable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
            this.emitter = emitter;
        });

        ConnectableObservable<Player> connectableObservable = playerUpdateObservable.share().publish();
        connectableObservable.connect();


        publisher = connectableObservable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }

    public Flowable<Player> getPublisher() {
        return this.publisher;
    }

}
```

I believe currently the only way to push new events into this observable is to call `onNext` programmatically.

My goal is

1. Change `PlayerUpdateObservable` such that every 10 seconds it'll send a `GET` http request and every time the response has changed, it'll propagate a new event:

```
Observable<Player> PlayerUpdateObservable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
            this.emitter = emitter;
        });
```

->

```
Observable<Player> PlayerUpdateObservable = Observable
.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.flatMap(tick -> sendHttpRequest())
.distinctUntilChanged();
```

2. Find some operator that will allow to return both new and previous value (the initial) for each new subscriber:

```
1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 2
        |
        v
  the moment of subscription
```

->

```
1 -> 2
```

I.e., it should push `1` as the very first value as well.

**Update**: it looks like I might use BehaviourSubject:

```
Observable<Long> nums = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
BehaviorSubject<Long> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

nums.subscribe(subject);

subject.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: @Henry not sure never worked with subjects before.

Comment: A subject is also an observable, see http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

Comment: @Henry is there an example about it / link to a playground where it saves the previous value?

Comment: @Henry I read about `BehaviorSubject` but I can't understand how I can make it have the previous value (and not the initial one).

Comment: Look at the marble diagram. The initial value will only be delivered as long as there is no other value.

Comment: @Henry it seems like I got it working: https://pastebin.com/dQzPjzrr. Is there a more elegant way to create a subject from Observable (I call onNext manually in the piece of code I sent)?

Comment: Does it make sense to say that if we create a subject from `Observable` it makes it a _hot_ one if the observable was _cold_?